# How can I add a unique identifier for each "account ID" in my database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am generating a temp table with duplicate entries for each "account ID". And I want all records with the same account ID to have an identifier. For example, all records with account ID: 1234 should have an identifier of 1. All records with account ID: 4321 should have an identifier of 2.

I have added a column to my temp table for this field, but I do not know how to populate it based off the account IDs.

Comment: So, you want all records with the same identifier to have an additional identifier?  I'm not quite sure I'm following the logic for why you want to do this - but this is easy to accomplish.  What is your DBMS?

Comment: Do you already have a table with (1234,1), (4321,2) mappings?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you working with?

Comment: may be you consider partitioning table into to tables in which account ID is primary key for one and foreign key for another table.

Comment: I am working in SQL Server Management Studio. I was hoping that having 1, 2, 3, etc. (INT) would be easier to work from than 1234, 4321 (VARCHAR). Really what I ultimately need to do is select the record with the MAX date associated to each account ID. Account ID 1234 has 2 records: one for date 1/1/2015, and one for date 1/20/2015. I ONLY want to pull the record for 1/20/2015 because it is the MAX date. I don't want to see any record but the one with the maximum date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an additional identifier, just group by your account number and select the max(date) for each, like:

```
Select accountID, max(lastUpdated)
from t
group by accountID
```

Comment: That worked perfectly... was trying to do something much more complicated - thank you!

Comment: if this (or any) answer was helpful, consider upvoting and/or accepting as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need another column to distinguish your rows. Let's assume you also have a date:

```
Accounts.AccountID
Accounts.Created
```

Let's find the original records:

```
SELECT 
 A.AccountID, 
 A.Created, 
 CASE WHEN 
  A.Created = MinCreated 
 THEN 
  1
 ELSE
  2
 AS "Version"
FROM
 Accounts AS A
INNER JOIN
(
 SELECT 
  AccountID, 
  MIN(Created)
 FROM
  Accounts 
 GROUP BY
  AccountID
) AS B
ON 
 A.AccountId = B.AccountId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DENSE_RANK()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173825.aspx) function with `ORDER BY AccountId`;

```
SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AccountId) Identifier
FROM YourTable
```

**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42696/1)**